# Delete the emails stored in a Google Form's responses

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-forms

### Background:

I am trying to create a google form that will be filled out by people, and then send a second form to be filled by someone else (couple). The form response needs to be anonymous, but the responses will also need to be linked.

My solution so far - using a unique ID for linking (kudos -> [How to assign a unique ID to a google form input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28682916/how-to-assign-a-unique-id-to-a-google-form-input)) then using the email inputted to send off a message with a pre-made link to the next form with the ID and then delete the email address from the sheet.

### The Question

The next sanitation which I am stuck on - is removing the email address form the Google Form response. One way would be to use `deleteAllResponses()` but that will also delete the basic data analysis pre-done by Google that I intend to use (to save time on creating some of the graphs).

I tried to find a way to access the response object and delete/modify the email field, but was unable to achieve that.

Would appreciate the help.

```
function myFunction() {
  //delete the last email that was added
  function deleteEmails(Row){
    sheet.getRange('B'+Row + ':B'+Row).clearContent();
  }
  
  //delete all responses - would like to change this to only delete/modify the email field.
  function deleteResponses() {
    var form = FormApp.openById('The form ID');
    form.deleteAllResponses();
  }
  
  //get the data on the sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("The sheet ID").getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  var StartRow = 1;
  var LastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var Range = sheet.getRange(LastRow, 2, 1, 62)
  var AllValues = Range.getValues();
  
  //if the person disagrees to fill the form - dont send an email
  if (AllValues[0][1] != 'disagree') {
    var SendTo = AllValues[0][0];
    var body = "Thank you for answering pfa a link for the sedond form";
  
    //send the actual email  
    MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: SendTo,
        cc: "",
        subject: 'Thank you for answering',
        htmlBody: body,
    }); 
  }
  
  //delete emails and responses
  deleteEmails(LastRow)
  deleteResponses()
}
```

Comment: AFAICT, You can't programmatically edit the already submitted Form response(You may try submitting the response with the same id).  What you can do is onFormSubmit, get the Form response->get itemResponses->Create a new FormResponse  with the given itemresponses(except email)->submit the new response->delete the current formResponse. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#createResponse()