# Parse error in google spreadsheet formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I am to generate an ID for a Google Forms-filled spreadsheet. My formula is from

[How to assign a unique ID to a google form input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28682916/how-to-assign-a-unique-id-to-a-google-form-input)

```
=arrayformula( if( len(A2:A), "" & text(row(A2:A) - row(A2) + 2, "000") & RIGHT(VALUE(A2:A), 3), iferror(1/0) ) )
```

but it gives a parse error.

Did Google Sheets formula syntax change since 2017? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this if it works for you:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A); 
 TEXT(ROW(A2:A) - ROW(A2) + 2; "000")&RIGHT(VALUE(A2:A); 3); IFERROR(1/0)))
```